# How to calculate equivalent futures position?

Tags: options, hedging, replication

Let's say I have the following two positions:

1. Buy ATM SPX call, expires in 1 month
2. Sell ATM SPX put, expires in 1 month

This creates a synthetic futures position.  How do I calculate how many futures are required to replicate (or hedge) my options position?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps I don't understand your question correctly but

**one** Synthetic Long Futures Construction 
equals
 "Buy **one** ATM Call" and "Sell **one** ATM Put"

(see e.g. here: http://www.theoptionsguide.com/synthetic-long-futures.aspx)

Comment: You are correct.  I failed to see that when you have a short put and a long call, you need a *short* future to hedge it.  I was just getting lost in my code, thanks.

Comment: I think this confusion happens to everybody at least once. You always have to remember that replication and hedging are two opposite sites of the same coin.

Comment: @sooprise If this answers your question, you can "accept" vonjd's answer by clicking the green arrow. That will indicate that this is the appropriate solution for anyone who sees your question in the future.

Comment: Chrisaycock, thanks for the reminder.  I'm a frequent user of StackOverflow, but when I'm in a less active sub-stackexchange, I get lazy about accepting answers.  Anyway, the answer has been checked, I think we're all square now :)